# Which App Store displays Traditional Chinese metadata?

Tags: iphone, localization, app-store, app-store-connect

iTunes Connect allows adding Traditional Chinese metadata, however I couldn't find any App Store (by country) that uses Traditional Chinese metadata...

I checked the most likely App Stores such as Hong Kong and Taiwan, but it seems they display UK English metadata rather than Chinese metadata.

Can anyone suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As listed [here](http://kb.tethras.com/localizing-your-ios-app/ios-device-language-support-app-store-territories-and-itunes-connect-default-languages) **Taiwan** and **Macau** display the traditional Chinese.

Comment: Thank for your answer. 
However, it doesn't seem to work while viewing on desktop browser... For example, try to view Appigo ToDo app (which supports both Simplified and Traditional Chinese) on the following URLs as follow:
1. https://itunes.apple.com/cn/app/todo/id408975584?mt=12
2. https://itunes.apple.com/tw/app/todo/id408975584?mt=12
3. https://itunes.apple.com/mo/app/todo/id408975584?mt=12

Link #1 will show page in Simplified Chinese as expected.
Link #2,#3 however, will show page in English rather than Traditional Chinese...

Any idea why?

Comment: @Joshua This is a new question, you should accept this answer as it answers your original question and then ask a new question

Comment: Im experiencing the same problem, i cant view the Chinese Traditional metadata for my app no matter what country I put in itunes URL. Did you manage to solve it?

Answer (score -1):

Try App Store in Taiwan. And you can temporarily change your store country in your account in iTunes.

Comment: This isn't adding anything new or useful that the previous answer already did

Comment: Hi! I recommend her that she uses iTunes as a tool to do. Not working on browser.